# How to get the video's duration or number of frames in ffmpeg filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm writing a filter in ffmpeg and I have to get the duration or number of frames in filter_frame function. But the parameters of "filter_frame" function only consist of AVFilterLink and AVFrame:

```
static int filter_frame(AVFilterLink* link, AVFrame* in) {
    AVFilterContext* avctx = link->dst;
    ExtractContext* privCtx = (ExtractContext*)avctx->priv;
    AVFilterLink* outlink = avctx->outputs[0];
    //here I want to get the duration of total number of frames:
}
```

I can't find attributes which is related to duration of frame numbers in either class. I have googles but all answers are about getting duration or frame numbers using ffmpeg.exe, which don't meet my requirements because I have to get them in self-written filter in FFMPEG. Thanks for your help!

Comment: please provide more details and a sample of code aswell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry that I'm new to stackoverflow and didn't know how to insert code before. I have inserted a code block and added supplements to my question.